# Expo SDK 33 Update Error in ExpoKit33 or React-native

Tags: react-native, expo

I was using SDK 30. And my app is a standalone app. 
 I was going to update SDK33 to launch a 64-bit app. 
So I did it in the order that it was written on the homepage. But I've made a lot of errors about where the problem is.

my app.bundle

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
  }

  dependencies {
    classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
  }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

repositories {
  maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}

android {
  compileSdkVersion 28
  buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'

  defaultConfig {
    applicationId 'com.jackson.myapp'
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 1
    versionName '1.0.0'
    ndk {
      abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
    }
    multiDexEnabled true
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    // Deprecated. Used by net.openid:appauth
    manifestPlaceholders = [
      'appAuthRedirectScheme': 'host.exp.exponent'
    ]
  }
  dexOptions {
    javaMaxHeapSize System.getenv("DISABLE_DEX_MAX_HEAP") ? null : "8g"
  }

  flavorDimensions 'minSdk'
  productFlavors {
    devMinSdk {
      dimension 'minSdk'
      // dev utilizes minSDKVersion = 21 to allow the Android gradle plugin
      // to pre-dex each module and produce an APK that can be tested on
      // Android Lollipop without time consuming dex merging processes.
      minSdkVersion 21
    }
    prodMinSdk {
      dimension 'minSdk'
      minSdkVersion 19
    }
  }
  buildTypes {
    debug {
      debuggable true
      ext.enableCrashlytics = false
    }
    release {
      minifyEnabled true
      proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
      zipAlignEnabled true
    }
  }
  signingConfigs {
    debug {
      storeFile file('../debug.keystore')
    }
  }
  lintOptions {
    abortOnError false
  }
  packagingOptions {
    pickFirst "**"
    exclude "lib/arm64-v8a/librealm-jni.so"

  }
  configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.force 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
  }

  compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility 1.8
    targetCompatibility 1.8
  }
}

// Don't use modern jsc-android since it still has some critical bugs that
// crash applications when the string for the JS bundle is loaded and when
// locale-specific date functions are called.
// configurations.all {
//   resolutionStrategy {
//     force 'org.webkit:android-jsc:r216113'
//   }
// }


apply from: 'expo.gradle'




dependencies {
  implementation project(':react-native-iap')
  implementation project(':react-native-fetch-blob')
  implementation project(':react-native-touch-id')
  implementation project(':react-native-keychain')
  implementation project(':react-native-fs')
  implementation project(':react-native-secure-randombytes')
  implementation project(':react-native-fast-crypto')
  implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
  api 'host.exp.exponent:expo-app-loader-provider:+'
  api 'org.unimodules:core:+'
  api 'org.unimodules:unimodules-constants-interface:+'
  api 'host.exp.exponent:expo-constants:+'
  api 'org.unimodules:unimodules-file-system-interface:+'
  api 'host.exp.exponent:expo-file-system:+'
  api 'org.unimodules:unimodules-image-loader-interface:+'
  api 'host.exp.exponent:expo-permissions:+'
  api 'org.unimodules:unimodules-permissions-interface:+'
  api 'org.unimodules:unimodules-sensors-interface:+'
  api 'host.exp.exponent:expo-react-native-adapter:+'
  api 'host.exp.exponent:expo-task-manager:+'
  api 'org.unimodules:unimodules-task-manager-interface:+'

// Optional universal modules, could be removed
// along with references in MainActivity
  api 'host.exp.exponent:expo-ads-admob:+'
  api 'host.exp.exponent:expo-app-auth:+'
  api 'host.exp.exponent:expo-analytics-segment:+'
  api 'org.unimodules:unimodules-barcode-scanner-interface:+'
  api 'host.exp.exponent:expo-barcode-scanner:+'
  api 'org.unimodules:unimodules-camera-interface:+'
  api 'host.exp.exponent:expo-camera:+'
  api 'host.exp.exponent:expo-contacts:+'
  api 'host.exp.exponent:expo-face-detector:+'
  api 'org.unimodules:unimodules-face-detector-interface:+'
  api 'host.exp.exponent:expo-font:+'
  api 'host.exp.exponent:expo-gl-cpp:+'
  api 'host.exp.exponent:expo-gl:+'
  api 'host.exp.exponent:expo-google-sign-in:+'
  api 'host.exp.exponent:expo-local-authentication:+'
  api 'host.exp.exponent:expo-localization:+'
  api 'host.exp.exponent:expo-location:+'
  api 'host.exp.exponent:expo-media-library:+'
  api 'host.exp.exponent:expo-print:+'
  api 'host.exp.exponent:expo-sensors:+'
  api 'host.exp.exponent:expo-sms:+'
  api 'host.exp.exponent:expo-background-fetch:+'
  implementation 'expolib_v1.com.google.android.exoplayer:expolib_v1-extension-okhttp:2.6.1@aar'


  apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native-unimodules/gradle.groovy"

  implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'

  // Our dependencies
  implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'

  // Our dependencies from ExpoView
  // DON'T ADD ANYTHING HERE THAT ISN'T IN EXPOVIEW. ONLY COPY THINGS FROM EXPOVIEW TO HERE.
  implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.34.0'
  implementation('com.facebook.android:audience-network-sdk:4.99.0') {
    exclude module: 'play-services-ads'
  }
  compileOnly 'org.glassfish:javax.annotation:3.1.1'
  implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.4.0'
  implementation 'de.greenrobot:eventbus:2.4.0'
  implementation 'com.amplitude:android-sdk:2.9.2' // Be careful when upgrading! Upgrading might break experience scoping. Check with Jesse. See Analytics.resetAmplitudeDatabaseHelper
  implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
  implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:15.0.1'
  implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:16.0.1'
  implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.1'
  implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:15.0.1'
  implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:15.0.1'
  implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:15.0.1'
  annotationProcessor 'com.raizlabs.android:DBFlow-Compiler:2.2.1'
  implementation "com.raizlabs.android:DBFlow-Core:2.2.1"
  implementation "com.raizlabs.android:DBFlow:2.2.1"
  implementation "com.madgag.spongycastle:core:1.53.0.0"
  implementation "com.madgag.spongycastle:prov:1.53.0.0"
  debugImplementation 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android-no-op:1.4-beta1'
  // debugImplementation 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android:1.4-beta1'
  releaseImplementation 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android-no-op:1.4-beta1'
  implementation 'com.facebook.device.yearclass:yearclass:1.0.1'
  implementation 'commons-io:commons-io:1.3.2'
  implementation 'me.leolin:ShortcutBadger:1.1.4@aar'
  implementation 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.9.5'
  implementation 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.4.7'
  implementation 'com.yqritc:android-scalablevideoview:1.0.1'
  implementation 'commons-codec:commons-codec:1.10'
  implementation 'com.segment.analytics.android:analytics:4.3.0'
  implementation 'com.google.zxing:core:3.2.1'
  implementation 'net.openid:appauth:0.4.1'
  implementation('com.airbnb.android:lottie:2.5.5')  {
      exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'appcompat-v7'
  }
  implementation('io.nlopez.smartlocation:library:3.2.11') {
    transitive = false
  }
  implementation 'com.android.support:exifinterface:28.0.0'
  implementation 'com.squareup.okio:okio:1.9.0'

  // Testing
  androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
  // We use a modified build of com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1. Explanation in maven-test/README
  androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
  androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support:support-annotations:28.0.0'
  androidTestImplementation 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:3.0.0'
  androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.uiautomator:uiautomator-v18:2.1.1'
  androidTestImplementation 'com.azimolabs.conditionwatcher:conditionwatcher:0.2'

  testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
  testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.10.19'
  testImplementation 'org.robolectric:robolectric:3.8'
  testImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2-alpha1'
  testImplementation 'com.android.support.test:rules:1.0.2-alpha1'






}

// This has to be down here for some reason
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

```
ERROR: Failed to resolve: org.unimodules:core:+
Show in Project Structure dialog
Affected Modules: app


ERROR: Failed to resolve: host.exp.exponent:expo-react-native-adapter:+
Show in Project Structure dialog
Affected Modules: app


ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@prodMinSdkDebug/compileClasspath': Could not find expolib_v1.com.google.android.exoplayer:expolib_v1-extension-okhttp:2.6.1.
Show Details
Affected Modules: app


ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@prodMinSdkDebugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not find expolib_v1.com.google.android.exoplayer:expolib_v1-extension-okhttp:2.6.1.
Show Details
Affected Modules: app


ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@prodMinSdkDebugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not find expolib_v1.com.google.android.exoplayer:expolib_v1-extension-okhttp:2.6.1.
Show Details
Affected Modules: app


ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@prodMinSdkRelease/compileClasspath': Could not find expolib_v1.com.google.android.exoplayer:expolib_v1-extension-okhttp:2.6.1.
Show Details
Affected Modules: app


ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@prodMinSdkReleaseUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not find expolib_v1.com.google.android.exoplayer:expolib_v1-extension-okhttp:2.6.1.
Show Details
Affected Modules: app


ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@devMinSdkDebug/compileClasspath': Could not find expolib_v1.com.google.android.exoplayer:expolib_v1-extension-okhttp:2.6.1.
Show Details
Affected Modules: app


ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@devMinSdkDebugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not find expolib_v1.com.google.android.exoplayer:expolib_v1-extension-okhttp:2.6.1.
Show Details
Affected Modules: app


ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@devMinSdkDebugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not find expolib_v1.com.google.android.exoplayer:expolib_v1-extension-okhttp:2.6.1.
Show Details
Affected Modules: app


ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@devMinSdkRelease/compileClasspath': Could not find expolib_v1.com.google.android.exoplayer:expolib_v1-extension-okhttp:2.6.1.
Show Details
Affected Modules: app


ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@devMinSdkReleaseUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not find expolib_v1.com.google.android.exoplayer:expolib_v1-extension-okhttp:2.6.1.
Show Details
Affected Modules: app
```

How can I fix this error? I don't know which part, so there's too much to solve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the project back to square one, and then executed it in order.

My difference is not using `npm` but using `Yarn`.

It was very effective, and I removed all the places where '`expolib_v1`' was present.

Answer (score 0):

Follow steps defined below "**If upgrading from SDK32 or below:**"

https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/expokit/expokit/#upgrading-expokit

Comment: Can not find `expolib_v1`

Comment: `apply from: '../../node_modules/react-native-unimodules/gradle.groovy'` is this already added to the top of the android/app/build.gradle ?

Comment: Install this too. https://github.com/unimodules/react-native-unimodules

Comment: I'm already added `gradle.groovy` and install `react-native-unimodules`

Comment: `apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native-unimodules/gradle.groovy"` move this to top of the app.build.gradle and remove  dependencies after `// Optional universal modules, could be removed`

Comment: Add import `import host.exp.exponent.generated.BasePackageList;` to top of **MainApplication.java** and remove existing expo.modules imports from **MainApplication.java** add following method `public List getExpoPackages() {
    return new BasePackageList().getPackageList();
}`